# Javascript string manupulation

Tags: javascript, string

there,

I am new to JavaScript, could you please help me for the following question ?

I have a string "AB_CD.1.23.3-609.7.8.EF_HI.XBXB"

1.23.3 and 609.7.8  are random numbers with two "." in between

AB_CD is random string with "_" in the middle

EF_HI.XBXB is also random string with "_" and "." in the middle

I would like to break it into two strings: AB_CD.1.23.3.EF_HI.XBXB (remove -609.7.8 in the middle) and AB_CD.6.7.8.EF_HI.XBXB (remove 1.23.3- in the middle).

Could anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried anything? A regex would seem like the proper solution.

Comment: That string have fixed length? And every substring is always at the same length?

Comment: what you have tried till now?

Comment: I tried string replace such as: string.replace("\-[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*", "");  also tried var re = /([A-Z]+\_[A-Z]+)\.([0-9]+\.[0-9]+.[0-9]+)-([0-9]+\.[0-9]+.[0-9]+)\.([A-Z]+\_[A-Z]+\.[A-Z]+\.[A-Z]+\.[A-Z]+)/ matches  = re.exec(string);  stringresult = matches[1] + '.' + matches[2] + '.' + matches[4]   but none works

Comment: see my answer below, check if it will work or not.

Comment: The string does not have fixed length.  The substrings do not at the same length either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since its looks like you are very new in javascript, so I will not show you the solution using regex.

Here is the simple solution by using split method only

```
var text="AB_CD.1.23.3-609.7.8.EF_HI.XBXB"
var text1=text.split('-');
var firsttext=text1[0].split('.')[0];
alert(firsttext+"."+text1[1]);
var secondtext=text1[1].split('.')[3];
alert(text1[0]+"."+secondtext);
```

Here is the fiddle [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/ranjitsss/ZPKa5/)

Comment: Thank you.  I got an error message "alert" is not defined."  Did I miss something?  Sorry I am very new to Javascript. May ask silly questions.

Comment: have you seen the fiddle??